# How to display clickable hyperlink

Tags: nativescript

We achieve this behaviour in android using a TextView with the property autoLink set to web.

<TextView android:autoLink="web" ... />

How to do that in NS?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have clickable links, you can use HtmlView instead of TextView. The thing is that instead of click, you will have to use long press.